# How to write in code blocks console?

Tags: c, console-application, codeblocks

I'm new to code blocks and I'm writing code that takes in a command line input such as a file name, but once I compile and run the Code the console prompts "press any key to continue" like always and I'm unable to type anything in the console? So I can I write in console making my code run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeBlocks will run your executable file without arguments, so you'll probably want to do it yourself. Open a command prompt (`cmd.exe`) and invoke your program with the desired arguments: `C:/path/to/your/project/bin/Debug/program.exe filename`.

Alternately you can request the user input via `scanf` or similar.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass commandline arguments to your program in the Code::Blocks
console, because Code::Blocks has already started your program when you
see the console. You need to specify any commandline arguments in the
the Project settings *before* you run it. Then, when the console appears,
your program will be running with the commandline arguments you have
specified.

To specify commandline arguments, select the **Project** menu on the
top menu-bar of the IDE. In the **Project** menu, select **Set program's
arguments**, enter the commandline arguments you want and then OK out.

Once your program *is* running in the console (with or without commandline
arguments), if it requests any input from the user, then you will be
able to type the required input in the console.